# Firebase user.getEmail() returning null

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I've implemented Firebase auth with email/pass authentication in my android app, and I want to know the signed in user's email, but user.getEmail() is returning null, even user.getDisplayName() is returning null. I've rightly uploaded the user's name during registration but the method's  returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are connected to data base? if not do this

```
val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
lateinit var mDatabase : DatabaseReference
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Names")
```

After that, use

```
    var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
```

To get the current user and do

```
        var uemail = user!!.email
```

To get the current user email